# Llenar un UICollectionView con items Vacios

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Estoy haciendo un collectionView, que quiero que contenga 7 items. El tema, es que cuando recién se inicia la app, mi array no contiene 7 elementos. Entonces, cuando va a cargar la página, me dice que el indice esta fuera de rango y es correcto.

Quisiera que si por ejemplo el array tiene 2 items, que los otros 5 se completen con información distinta del array.[image: Ahi lo muestro en el código]

Comment: no coloques el return como item = 7 - array... se rompe por que si tu array trae solo 2 items solamente te reconocerá los dos, después el compilador no sabe como llenar las celdas y pues como estas creando la celda de con un forceUnrwapp truena, yo te sugiero, que la lógica la hagas desde tu celda... con un didSet usando una estructura par llenar los datos a la celda, eso seria una buena practica, y dentro de la celda le colocas lo que quieres que se vea por default.. si tengo un poco de tiempo enseguida te subo unas imágenes para darte un ejemplo mas claro saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que en `numberOfItemsInSection` siempre regreses la cantidad de elementos que tiene tu arreglo, en este caso `works.count`, precisamente para evitar inconsistencias como la que estás enfrentando.

Una vez establecido esto, el problema se convierte en cómo actualizar el collection view cuando se modifica el arreglo. En su comentario, @Yan Cervantes te da una opción, otra puede ser añadir un método para pedir el nuevo arreglo y actualizarlo, ese método se vería así:

```
func actualizar(works: [Work]) {
    self.works = works
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

`reloadData()` es uno de los métodos para actualizar el contenido, puede que sea muy pesado si, por ejemplo, sólo se añadió un elemento al arreglo. Dependerá de lo que estés haciendo.

---

Si realmente quieres llenar la celda de alguna forma distinta a sacar la información del arreglo, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_PORTFOLIO_CELL, for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row < works.count { // elemento en el arreglo
        //código que ya tienes
        let work = works[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageWork.loadImage(work.imageUrl)
        cell.idLabel.text = work.id
        //...
    } else { // no está en el arreglo, sacarlos de otro lugar
        cell.imageWork.loadImage("https://...")
        cell.idLabel.text = "trabajo"
    }
}
```

Siento que de esta forma quedaría frágil y en cualquier momento acabará mostrando información que no era la esperada. Sugiero fuertemente la primer opción.